# telerik radgrid - get client side sibling cell value in javascript

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

I have an asp.net radgrid that contains a column thusly:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="RenewsContainer" HeaderText="Renews" HeaderStyle-Width="60px" ItemStyle-Width="60px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRenewsView" runat="server" Checked='<%#Eval("Renews")%>' onclick="checkboxChange(this);" />
   </ItemTemplate>
   <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRenews" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("Renews") %>' />
   </EditItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Notice the `onclick="checkboxChange(this)`. This works fine, but inside that checkBoxChange() function I need to access the checkbox state (checked/unchecked) of a sibling GridCheckBoxColumn checked state. I don't know how to get the row index (or rowid) of the checked row, and even when the row is obtained, I don't know how to get the checked state of that GridCheckBoxColumn (uniquename: "Locked").

Seems like there could be 2 approaches to this, at least:

1. Inside the checkboxChange() function, pass as an arg the current row index or telerik rowid. I don't know how to get this.
2. Inside the js function, somehow determine the row index or rowid of the row containing the checkbox that was clicked.

And then once the rowid/rowidx is obtained, how to get that sibling checked state?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you give your checkbox a unique CssClass and then use jQuery to select it right out of the DOM?  The RadGrid is a programmatic wrapper, but if you inspect the rendered HTML it's just a DIV/Table like anything else.

```
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRenewsView" runat="server" CssClass="MyCheckBox" Checked='<%#Eval("Renews")%>' onclick="checkboxChange(this);" />
   </ItemTemplate>

//jQuery
var isChecked = $(".MyCheckBox").is(':checked');
```

Comment: Maybe but there could be any number of rows. How would I know which row to look at?

Comment: I see what you're saying.  Keeping that in mind, you could either try to implement the native RadGrid client OnRowClick methods and work backward to find the checkbox in that row.  Or you could set the CSSClass of your checkbox in the OnRowDataBound event in code behind.  Use the Key of the row or incrementing row id and add it to the end of the CssClass of the checkbox.  This way, you will have a handle both on the checkbox, and also on the index or client data key of the row, and able to get a handle on it in JavaScript.